Каким должен быть url запроса для группового действия в restapi?
В разработке стараюсь следовать рекомендациям RestApi, поэтому для закрытия одной задачи в webapi реализовал обработчик put запроса для закрытия одной задачи по следующему url  /tasks/{taskId}/close. Подскажите каким должен быть url обработчика для закрытия задач выбранных пользователем в системе, я предполагаю что это будет put запрос в теле которого будет список идентификаторов задач, но вот каким будет url не соображу.

Могу ошибаться, но мне кажется, что /tasks/{taskId}/close должен быть не PUT, а POST. А для батч запроса будет /tasks/close (POST) с телом, где указаны id. Обосновать, к сожалению, не могу - руководствуюсь наитием (по личному опыту).

/tasks/close тоже думаю про этот вариант, но только put потому что post использую для создания

Для создания в идеале должен быть POST на /tasks.

PUT (= PATCH) - изменение чего либо. Например, если бы вместо прямого закрытия вы создавали заявки на закрытие (где указывается будущее время закрытия), то PUT можно было бы использовать для изменения этих заявок.

я не смог для себя определить когда put когда patch поэтому при изменении существующего объекта(редактирование, изменение статуса и.т.п) использую put запрос, создание задач конечно же post на url /tasks
